# Cell Focus from another sheet DoubleClick Vba Excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
     Dim f As Range
     If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
            Set f = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TARJETAS").Columns("B:B").Find( _
                                 what:=Target.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                Cancel = True
                HojaCliente.Activate
                f.Select
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to recreate the following event: Double click on a cell in the sheet where I am located and I want to focus on that row that has the same element but on another sheet.

I manage to select the cell but I can't manage to go through all those columns and then position myself in that column.

Should I do some traversal of all the columns on the other sheet and then do an if conditional?

Comment: Are you looking for Target.Value in a specific column on the other sheet?

Comment: If exactly that focus the value of another column but on another sheet.

Comment: Can the value you're looking for be *anywhere* on the other sheet, or is it in a specific column?

Comment: If we say that in this case it is in column C

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
     Dim f As Range, wsSearch As Worksheet
     If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L:L")) Is Nothing Then
            Set wsSearch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja8")
            Set f = wsSearch.Columns(3).Find( _
                              what:=Target.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing then
                Cancel = True
                wsSearch.Activate
                f.Select
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Adjust:

- `Range("L:L")` to the column where you are double-clicking
- `"Hoja8"` to the sheet name where you want to search
- `Columns(3)` to the column where you want to search for the value

Comment: I tried the code and it didn't work, it doesn't generate the search in the other sheet

Comment: I tested this - it does work.  If it's not working for you then possibly your search term is not an exact match for the value on the other sheet.

Comment: Your sheet 8 is where you aim to look? are you looking for column

Comment: `Hoja8.Columns(3).Find` - you mentioned column C above, and your posted code uses `Hoja8` as the worksheet.  If you want something different you need to describe what it is.

Comment: ..but your other question mentions ColB so in that case use `Hoja8.Columns(2).Find`

Comment: I sincerely apologize, I use the translator to communicate with you. Maybe this some words write them incorrectly, I will try again and I tell you-

Comment: I have some more information for you, imagine that I am on sheet 2 and I need to go to the client sheet, on sheet 2 is where I press in Column C and in Column B is where I will perform the search to locate myself in that cell.

Comment: Is the sheet protected does it affect anything?

Comment: I left you an edit of the code. And well unfortunately if the information matches

Comment: Sorry I missed the second worksheet reference in my edit.  See my last change.

Comment: Probe, with the same change and I continue with the problem, no element focuses on me and well if they coincide, I leave you some photos here for reference?